# Using SiriKit on watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, siri

Is it possible to start/stop a workout by Siri on Apple Watch? I believe It must work but I cannot find any docs about it.

I fount only it http://jamesonquave.com/blog/adding-siri-to-ios-10-apps-in-swift-tutorial/ but it works for iOS not for watchOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it would be impossible as the [Intents framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents) is only available on iOS (and MacOS).

Comment: Wouldn't have posted mine if I saw yours. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

The intents framework is now [available on watchOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/creating_an_intents_app_extension?language=objc). You have to make a separate watch intents extension and add it to your watchOS application.

Note that network requests on the watch simulator take about five seconds each, so if your Siri extension does network requests, it can take a while to respond (13 seconds in my case).

Answer (score 1):

It is currently impossible to do so. This may very well become a functionality in later releases to watchOS, but as it stands right no; no, there's no way to do such a task.